# Python: "expected an indented block" error after for loop at end of document

Tags: python, indentation

I know there are a few similar questions here, but please stick with me here for a second. 
I know how the indentation in python works, but the following problem kind of baffles me.

Consider the following code:

```
# Plot with mnist plot
for sel_err in sel_error:
    plot_mnist(x_test[sel_err], y_pred[sel_err], labels=labels[i], k_plots=10, prefix='Predicted class')
```

This will give me the following error: 
**Error     expected an indented block**

However if I add something unrelated to the code without changing the indentation it works. 
The following code will give me no errors whatsoever:

```
# Plot with mnist plot
for sel_err in sel_error:
    plot_mnist(x_test[sel_err], y_pred[sel_err], labels=labels[i], k_plots=10, prefix='Predicted class')
    print("hello world")
```

I might add, that both code samples are at the very end of the document, however I have made sure that there are no hidden tabstobs or anything similar after the code. 
Any idea as to why I get this error here?

**EDIT:**

Here is the complete code from the method to verify:

```
def ex_3_b(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    """
    Solution for exercise 3 b)
    :param x_train: Training samples (2-dimensional)
    :param y_train: Training labels
    :param x_test: Testing samples (2-dimensional)
    :param y_test: Testing labels
    :return:
    """

    labels = range(1, 6)

    clfLin = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovr', kernel='linear', C=10.0)
    clfLin.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clfLin.predict(x_test);
    confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred,labels)
    print(np.matrix(confusion_mat))
    plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_mat, labels)

    # Numpy indices to select images that are misclassified.
    sel_error = np.where(y_test != y_pred)
    # should be the label number corresponding the largest classification errors
    i = 3
    # Plot with mnist plot
    for sel_err in sel_error:
        plot_mnist(x_test[sel_err], y_pred[sel_err], labels=labels[i], k_plots=10, prefix='Predicted class')
```

And some strange behaviour I have found during debugging. As it seems the variable `sel_error` is causing some problems:
[image]
[image]
I'm actually not quite sure what is happening here, does the debugger see an additional variable? (Note: cursor is placed in the `sel_error` variable in both pictures.)

Comment: Hmm... some more context? Where are you running this from?

Comment: Also consider including the entire code!

Comment: I run this on Visual Studio 2017, Python Environment is Anaconda 2018.12. About the code: This is for a university assignment, so I'm not sure if I am allowed to post the entire code here.

Comment: We don't need the entire code, just a [mcve]. I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, but some things to look out for: 1) consistency, either indents or spaces; 2) the PEP8 formatting convention specifies that a newline should be added at the end of every file. Other than that, I think I'll stand by "try turning it off and on".

Comment: Hmm, I found some additional strange behaviour. I will include the code of the complete function in the OP and add some edits.

Comment: It sounds like you've got some sort of invisible or lookalike characters causing problems. I suggest deleting a few lines centered around the apparent problem location and retyping it.

Comment: @user2357112 As weird as it is, this seems to be the case. I have played around with several lines from the code (deleted, written out again manually) and now the error is gone, even though the code is still basically the same.